# Time Complexity for f1(n) / f2(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What are some algorithms which we can use that has fraction equation  time complexities? ( like 100n / 2n+1 for example )

Comment: i mean i need some of java code example which its time complexity can be like f1(n) / f2(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complexities isn't some sort of precise algebra calculations. Function f(x) belongs to a class, if you can multiply one of class' functions g(x) by a constant C, and show it always greater than your function -- simply said, you have to show that there exists a non infinite value C so that the equation is true for sufficiently big x:

f(x) <= C * g(x)

So e.g. 3n + 5 belongs to O(n), because 3n + 5 <= 1000n.

In a similar vain, you can show that 100n / (2n + 1) <= 50n, and thus its complexity belongs to O(n).

Edit: It also belongs to O(1), because 100n / (2n + 1) <= 50*1.